# How do i start with vertical gardening?

Tags: gardening, vertical-gardening

I have heard about vertical gardening for a couple of years now. I recently moved to a bigger flat, with some windows i think will fit for vertical gardening. My only problem is i don't know where to start. Do you have a list of things i need to know when starting? Or is there some sites selling a "start-package" with a water pump and some pots to have herbs in?

Comment: This question would be on-topic over at [gardening.SE](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think it's relevant on sustainability